# "Des richtige" oder "Das richtige"?

Tags: grammaticality

Irgendwo habe ich diesen Satz gesehen. Aber ich weiß nicht, warum hier "des richtige" geschrieben wurde.

> Unser Konversationskurs ist genau **des richtige** für Sie.

Hier ist der ganze Text:

> Wollen Sie Ihr Deutsch aktiv und praktisch verbessern?
>
> Wollen Sie sich flüssig auf Deutsch ausdrücken können und zahlreiche
>   neue Vokabeln, Phrasen und Redewendungen lernen?
>
> Möchten Sie die Angst vor dem Sprechen verlieren, ohne sich mit
>   Gammatik aufzuhalten?
>
> Dann ist unser Konversationskurs genau des richtige für Sie.

Comment: It's a typo....

Comment: Good thing that it’s a conversation course and not a writing course …

Comment: Wenn da beim letzen Satz im Original auch tatsächlich noch der Punkt am Ende fehlt, enthält diese Werbung sogar drei Fehler. Ich wäre bei einem Deutschkurs, der in seinem Aushängeschild schon mit so vielen Fehlern daherkommt, ein wenig skeptisch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast  Danke, den Punkt habe ich vergessen .

Comment: Phrasen sollte man in einem deutschen Konversationskurs besser nicht lernen.

Comment: Und wo hast Du es gelesen? "Irgendwo" ist sehr unpräzise, der Kontext wäre interessant, etwa in einem Comedy-Drehbuch, einer Anzeige, einem Roman usw. Wenn Du den Text wortgetreu zitieren kannst wirst Du das sicher genauer wissen.

Comment: Das habe ich in einer Anzeige im Internet gelesen .  @userunknown

Comment: Ich finde das ungewöhnlich, dass jemand Werbung für eine Sache macht, und man diesen Werbetext dann nicht mit einer Suchmaschine finden kann.

Answer (score 6):

Either there are two typos in the sentence, or it is the reproduction of Bavarian colloquial speech (plus still a typo).

The correct sentence in standard German would be:

> Unser Konversationskurs ist genau **das Richtige** für Sie.

So, the article should be »*das*« and the following noun should be capitalized.

---

In some Bavarian dialects the neuter article in nominative case is not »*das*«, but »*des*«. So in colloquial speech you sometimes might hear exactly this sentence. This is not really wrong, it is just non-standard German. You will often hear it in the south of Germany and in Austria, but it is very rare, that this will be written.

There are no binding orthographic rules for writing dialects or colloquial speech. But no matter which set of rules you may invent for writing this, it should be consistent. So either you write both nouns capitalized (»Konversationskurs« and »Richtige«) or you use all lowercase letters for both nouns (»konversationskurs« and »richtige«). Later is not recommended. Even when writing colloquial speech, it would be wise to apply as many standard orthographic rules as possible.

So if this really was Bavarian colloquial speech, you should write it this way:

> Unser Konversationskurs ist genau **des Richtige** für Sie.

But my guess is, that it should be standard German and contains two typos.

Comment: *Des* is only one neuter definite article in Bavarian; *as* is another.

Comment: *Des* instead of *das* is also used in at least one other dialect (Hessisch), and probably other dialects as well. (Some people would even say that nearly every vowel changes to "e" in Hessisch: Gewwe Se mer des emol her.)

Answer (score 2):

"Des" is colloquial language and is used in many dialects instead of "das".